# Multi-Level Configs Using config.setdefault()

Tags: python, dictionary, config

I'm looking for an easy way to handle multi-level dictionaries using the `config.setdefault()` method. Here's an example:

```
config = {}

config.setdefault("key1", 10)
config.setdefault("key2", {'x': 1, 'y': 2})
config.setdefault("key3", 5)
```

For `"key2"`, I would like to set defaults for both `'x'` and `'y'` keys. Is this possible? Let me know if I need to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

`.setdefault()` doesn't work that way. It accepts a single value argument.

One could `.update(new_dict)` to incorporate new key / value pairs.
But if it lists any pre-existing keys,
the existing values would be overwritten.
So that's not quite it.

You are looking for "merge dictionaries".
We construct a new dict, and give the old `config`
a chance to overwrite any newly proposed values.
Notice that `c` retains its old value.

```
>>> config = dict(c=1)
>>> config = {**{'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'c': 4}, **config}
>>> config
{'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'c': 1}
```

---

If you have dictionaries `a` and `b`,
then

```
{**a, **b}
```

will merge them.

Comment: While this works, it's not quite true. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question here, it was a simpler solution than I thought. The following code does what I was wanting.

```
config = {}

config.setdefault("key1", 10)
config.setdefault("key2", {}).setdefault('x', 1)
config.setdefault("key2", {}).setdefault('y', 2)
config.setdefault("key3", 5)

print(config)

{'key1': 10, 'key2': {'x': 1, 'y': 2}, 'key3': 5}
```